# Removing a tag from an appended element by its class/id

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, jqlite

I have the following code, and I cant get the previously appended text "You are now editing this" removed from the DOM when the user moves to edit something else. Any advice would be much appreciated. I am trying to avoid using jQuery too as I think it can be achieved with jQLite. Many thanks.

```js
var editApp = angular.module('editApp', ['ngRoute']);

editApp.directive('editInPlace', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      value: '=editInPlace'
    },
    template: '<span ng-click="edit()" ng-bind="value"></span><input ng-model="value"></input>',
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
      // Let's get a reference to the input element, as we'll want to reference it.
      var inputElement = angular.element(element.children()[1]);

      // This directive should have a set class so we can style it.
      element.addClass('edit-in-place');

      // Initially, we're not editing.
      $scope.editing = false;

      // ng-click handler to activate edit-in-place
      $scope.edit = function() {
        $scope.editing = true;

        // We control display through a class on the directive itself. See the CSS.
        element.addClass('active');
        element.append('<b class="yaet">You are now editing this</b>');
        // And we must focus the element. 
        // `angular.element()` provides a chainable array, like jQuery so to access a native DOM function, 
        // we have to reference the first element in the array.
        inputElement[0].focus();
      };

      // When we leave the input, we're done editing.
      inputElement.prop('onblur', function() {
        $scope.editing = false;
        element.removeClass('active');
        element.remove('.yaet'); // This is bit that fails
      });
    }
  };
});

editApp.controller('ContactsCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.contacts = [{
    number: '+25480989333',
    name: 'sharon'
  }, {
    number: '+42079872232',
    name: 'steve'
  }];
});
```

```css
.edit-in-place span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.edit-in-place input {
  display: none;
}
.edit-in-place.active span {
  display: none;
}
.edit-in-place.active input {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="editApp">
  <div ng-controller="ContactsCtrl">
    <h2>Contacts</h2>
    <br />
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
        <span edit-in-place="contact.number"></span> |
        <span edit-in-place="contact.name"></span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <br />
    <p>Here we repeat the contacts to ensure bindings work:</p>
    <br />
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
        {{contact.number}} | {{contact.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you plese explain more your problem? I ran your snippet and text "you are editing this" is correctly removing from dom.

Comment: Hi, yes, it removes, but it is actually removing all the html of the element variable, and I only want it to remove the tags and contents where class=yaet. Hope that explains. Sorry for being unclear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to select `.yaet` by class and remove them. Since you want to use jqLite, you will have to select elements manually, for example like this:

```
inputElement.prop('onblur', function() {
    $scope.editing = false;
    element.removeClass('active');
    angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.yaet')).remove();
});
```

```js
var editApp = angular.module('editApp', ['ngRoute']);

editApp.directive('editInPlace', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope: {
      value: '=editInPlace'
    },
    template: '<span ng-click="edit()" ng-bind="value"></span><input ng-model="value"></input>',
    link: function($scope, element, attrs) {
      // Let's get a reference to the input element, as we'll want to reference it.
      var inputElement = angular.element(element.children()[1]);

      // This directive should have a set class so we can style it.
      element.addClass('edit-in-place');

      // Initially, we're not editing.
      $scope.editing = false;

      // ng-click handler to activate edit-in-place
      $scope.edit = function() {
        $scope.editing = true;

        // We control display through a class on the directive itself. See the CSS.
        element.addClass('active');
        element.append('<b class="yaet">You are now editing this</b>');
        // And we must focus the element. 
        // `angular.element()` provides a chainable array, like jQuery so to access a native DOM function, 
        // we have to reference the first element in the array.
        inputElement[0].focus();
      };

      // When we leave the input, we're done editing.
      inputElement.prop('onblur', function() {
        $scope.editing = false;
        element.removeClass('active');
        angular.element(element[0].querySelector('.yaet')).remove();
      });
    }
  };
});

editApp.controller('ContactsCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.contacts = [{
    number: '+25480989333',
    name: 'sharon'
  }, {
    number: '+42079872232',
    name: 'steve'
  }];
});
```

```css
.edit-in-place span {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.edit-in-place input {
  display: none;
}
.edit-in-place.active span {
  display: none;
}
.edit-in-place.active input {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.2.28/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="editApp">
  <div ng-controller="ContactsCtrl">
    <h2>Contacts</h2>
    <br />
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
        <span edit-in-place="contact.number"></span> |
        <span edit-in-place="contact.name"></span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <br />
    <p>Here we repeat the contacts to ensure bindings work:</p>
    <br />
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="contact in contacts">
        {{contact.number}} | {{contact.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this completely solves the issue. Very impressed by the skills of people on this board.

Answer (score 1):

I think its not possible without jQuery because jQLite doesnt know selectors by class.

Also

```
  element.remove('.yaet'); // This is bit that fails
```

Calling element.remove() , function remove does not have any parameters so you are removing actual element.

Alternative in jquery would be

$(".yeat").remove() , but you are calling $(element).remove().

If jQuery is your foe you should try vanilla JS

```
 var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".yaet");
 elements.remove();
```